# When to use INVOKE_SINGLE_THREADED or INVOKE_NONVIRTUAL when invoking method on com.sun.jdi.ObjectReference?

Tags: java, debugging, jvmti, jdi

When invoking a method on an `com.sun.jdi.ObjectReference` instance, you have to provide some `options`: either `INVOKE_SINGLE_THREADED`, or `INVOKE_NONVIRTUAL`.

```java
invokeMethod​(ThreadReference thread, Method method, List<? extends Value> arguments, int options)
```

According to the Javadoc:

> *INVOKE_SINGLE_THREADED*: Perform method invocation with only the
> invoking thread resumed
> *INVOKE_NONVIRTUAL*: Perform non-virtual method
> invocation

But I am still confused what these options mean.

Comment: These two flags are not connected at all. You could specify both together when it fits. So “what is the difference between them” is not a meaningful question.

Comment: @Holger, got it, but I still don't know what they do

Comment: `INVOKE_SINGLE_THREADED`: resume only the invoking thread (rather than all JVM threads). `INVOKE_NONVIRTUAL`: invoke the specified declared method, ignoring overriding methods (rather than using the standard method lookup).